# xsl:variable en condición de select no funciona

Tags: xml, xpath, xsl

Tengo una Ruta con una condición en la cual al insertarle una Variable en la condición [GRUPO/@REFERENCE = $VALOR] no lo esta tomando.

```
<xsl:variable name="valor" select="G1"/>
<xsl:for-each select="//ITEM/REFERENCES[GRUPO/@REFERENCE = $valor]/MODEL">      
    <xsl:value-of select="$valor"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

La variable esta dentro de un For-each y va cambiando de acuerdo al listado la cual funciona correctamente

Si cambio el valor por un literal

```
<xsl:variable name="valor" select="G1"/>
<xsl:for-each select="//ITEM/REFERENCES[GRUPO/@REFERENCE = 'G1']/MODEL">     
    <xsl:value-of select="$valor"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya probaste?:

```
<xsl:variable name="valor" select="'G1'"/>
```

**Actualización**

Creo que debes hacer algo así:

```
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when select="//ITEM/REFERENCES[GRUPO/@REFERENCE = 'G1']/MODEL">
    <span style="color:#000000; font-size:12px; ">
        <xsl:text>Caso 1</xsl:text>
    </span>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:when select="//ITEM/REFERENCES[GRUPO/@REFERENCE = 'G2']/MODEL">
    <span style="color:#000000; font-size:12px; ">
        <xsl:text>Caso 2</xsl:text>
    </span>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
        <span style="font-size:12px; ">
            <xsl:text>De otro modo</xsl:text>
        </span>
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Comment: La variable va cambiando por un for-each, por lo que no puede ser un valor fijo. De todas formas lo probe y tampoco reconoce a la variable.

Comment: La variable es un valor que esta en el xml??

Comment: Si, y se actualiza antes de llegar a la cuestión. La variable se actualiza , funciona perfecto pero al meterla en el select="" no esta colocando el valor  intente ponerla entre ($valor) pero tampoco

Comment: Ya actualice pero la verdad no se si es eso lo que busques. Como que falta que pongas el xml de donde quieres extraer los datos.

Comment: Esa solución no me sirve porque no es una lista finita.

Comment: Bueno por lo visto, si te sirvio.